# Are my tags getting overloaded or is this a scope issue with add constructors to a yaml config or something else

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Wrote a helper function to wrap simple object constructors and make them accessible as tags but I either have a bug or writing the constructors as closures is causing a collision

```
import yaml
from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError


def add_init_constuctors(*klasses, loader=yaml.SafeLoader):
    for klass in klasses:
        name = klass.__name__

        def constructor(loader, node):
            try:
                fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
            except ConstructorError:
                fields = {}

            return klass(**fields)

        yaml.add_constructor(
            f"!{name}",
            constructor,
            Loader=loader,
        )
        print(f"added !{name}")
        print(yaml.load(f"!{name}", Loader=loader))

    print(
        [
            (klass.__name__, yaml.load(f"!{klass.__name__}", Loader=loader))
            for klass in klasses
        ]
    )

class A(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A()"

class B(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B()"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_init_constuctors(A, B)
```

running this code outputs

```
added !A
A()
added !B
B()
[('A', B()), ('B', B())]
```

As you can see when the `A` is added it's loads correctly, but once the `B` tag is added, attempting to access the `A` returns the `B` constructor

I expect, even though they're enclosed in the scope the functions defined in the closure would stay with constructor tags and be correct / accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your inner function has a closure over the `klass` variable, i.e. whenever `constructor` executes, it looks up the *current* value of `klass`, not the one it had when the constructor was added.

The simplest way around this is to generate the constructor in a function (I removed the `sklearn` stuff because it's irrelevant to the question):

```py
import yaml
from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError

class A(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A()"

class B(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B()"

def gen_constructor(klass):
    def ret(loader, node):
        try:
            fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
        except ConstructorError:
            fields = {}
        return klass(**fields)
    return ret

def add_init_constuctors(*klasses, loader=yaml.SafeLoader):
    for klass in klasses:
        name = klass.__name__

        yaml.add_constructor(
            f"!{name}",
            gen_constructor(klass),
            Loader=loader,
        )
        print(f"added !{name}")
        print(yaml.load(f"!{name}", Loader=loader))

    print(
        [
            (klass.__name__, yaml.load(f"!{klass.__name__}", Loader=loader))
            for klass in klasses
        ]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_init_constuctors(A, B)
```

Now, `res` captures the argument `klass` of the function `gen_constructor`, rather than the variable `klass` inside `add_init_constructors`. Therefore, the output is:

```
added !A
A()
added !B
B()
[('A', A()), ('B', B())]
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help, editing the question so it maps more clearly to your answer.